# Position Other DIVs based on the position of a specific DIV in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am still new to web so this is kinda tricky for me. I have a class greenApple01

```
.greenApple01 {
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    background-image: url("fingertwisterimages/newimages/spritesheet_greenApple.png");
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    right: 130px;
}
```

And I have another div yellowApple03.

Now what I want to achieve is this:

[image]

How can I position yellowApple03 based on greenApple01's position? Also, I am developing for mobile and can you give me ideas on how to utilize media queries?

Comment: Any reason to use `absolute` positioning?

Comment: Hi. Actually that was an example I saw on the web. I am still figuring out how to use CSS. Is absolute not needed here?

Answer (score 4):

There will be no chance to position elements relative to each other if they're positioned `absolute`ly as they are removed from normal flow.

If you have planned to align the elements vertically at the middle in the same line, you could simply `display` them as `inline-block` and then give `vertical-align: middle;` declaration to them for vertical alignment.

```css
.greenApple01, .yellowApple03 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You could play with `margin` if you want to add some spaces between those elements. For instance, assuming `.yellowApple03` is placed after the `.greenApple01`:

```css
.yellowApple03 { margin-left: 100px; }
```

Also mind the [gap between inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) which increases the actual space between elements and may causes a trouble.

Comment: Hi @Hashem Qolami. Thanks. Based on this, can I use this even if I have more elements? I have a total of 8 images that needs positioning.

Comment: @MiguelRivera Of course. Just keep in mind: inline-level elements (`inline`/`inline-block`) sit beside each other like words; If there isn't enough room inside the container, they will wrap. In that cases we usually give `white-space: nowrap` to container and then reset it to `normal` on children if needed so.

Answer (score 2):

absolute and relative positioning are very powerful and misunderstood concepts in CSS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nzhONbfFRG17R44EHI5C?p=preview

In a nutshell, if you absolute position something, it will become bounded within the closest parent level element with a position other than default.

Eg 1.

```
<body>
   <div class='parent'>
       <div class='apple1' style='position:absolute'></div>
       <div class='apple2' style='position:absolute'></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

In this case the 2 apples will both be positioned relative to the body

Eg 2.

```
<body>
   <div class='parent' style='position:relative'>
       <div class='apple1' style='position:absolute'></div>
       <div class='apple2' style='position:absolute'></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

In this case the 2 apples will both be positioned relative to the div with the 'parent' class because it has a position value.

So, to solve what you want to do, just make sure your yellow apple is a child element of your green apple. That way your yellow apple will be positioned in relation to wherever your green apple is being shown.

```
<body>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='greenApple01' style='position:absolute'>
            <div class='yellowApple03' style='position:relative'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, based on example 2. If `apple2` is child of `apple1`, whatever margin I put in `apple2` class, it will be applied starting on `apple1`'s position?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Here is a plunker to make things a little clearer. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/nzhONbfFRG17R44EHI5C?p=preview.

In the third example you will notice that all I did was create another green apple the same way and change where it was positioned, as a result, the yellow apple was positioned relative to it in the same way.